Magento 2 : Meta Tag in Dashboard
I have an issue with the meta tag in Magento 2. Where in admin I can add Facebook or any social media meta tag or key?

by default magento may not support meta tags or pixels. it support only google analytics, for meta, there are multiple extensions available.

You need to create your own plugin to achieve this kind of problem.

is there a free plugin that I can use?

I have added a solution to add meta tags without installing any third-party extension.

Magento Default not provided any functionality for meta tags or pixels.
So here you have 2 options.

Create your Own extension from scratch according to the requirement.
Use ready made extension which available into market which full fill your requirements.


Please follow the below snippet to add Facebook or any social media meta tag or key.
Step 1: Create the below file inside your custom theme

app/design/frontend/Jigar/customtheme/Magento_Theme/layout/default.xml

Step 2: Create the below file and add your meta tags and keys

app/design/frontend/Jigar/customtheme/Magento_Theme/templates/html/opengraph/general.phtml

<?php
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
?>

<meta property="og:title" content="YOUR TITLE HERE" />
<meta property="og:description" content="YOUR DESCRIPTION HERE" />
<meta property="og:locale" content="YOUR LOCALE HERE" />
<meta property="og:type" content="YOUR TYPE HERE" />
<meta property="og:url" content="YOUR URL HERE" />
<meta property="og:site_name" content="YOUR SITENAME HERE" />

<!-- other properties here -->

